# Using Google Comlink for web workers with React/Typescript results in DOM Exception

Tags: reactjs, typescript, csv, blob, web-worker

I'm currently have a CSV parsing app using papaparse with a React/Typescript stack, and I'm trying to offload some of that work to a web worker. I set up the worker in this file:

```
import { parseFunc } from '../src/parsing'

const exported = {
  parseFunc,
}
export type ParseWorker = typeof exports

expose(exported)
```

along with an associated tsconfig.json in the same directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "webworker",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "baseUrl": "."
  }
}
```

and then I load and attempt to run it here:

```
  import { wrap } from 'comlink'
  const worker = new Worker('../../../customWebWorkers', {
    name: 'customWebWorkers',
    type: 'module',
  })
  const workerApi = wrap<import('../../../customWebWorkers').ParseWorker>(
    worker
  )
  return await workerApi.parseFunc({
    csvData
  })
```

Running this locally works just fine! The issue comes when I try to push my app to the currently running version, I run into this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker':
Script at 'https://myWebStorage/customWebWorkers.132234d2.chunk.worker.js' 
cannot be accessed from origin 'https://csv-parser-132.com'.
    at...
```

I've looked at a few alternate solutions online, the two most common being using a Blob to get a url to the object of the script and loading it that way, or using importScripts: unfortunately neither of these seem to work for my use-case. If I try those solutions, I instead get this error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I believe this is due to the above solutions not incorporating the tsconfig file.

I know this is quite a difficult question but any possible answers would be appreciated! I'm quite surprised that running web workers in a typescript/React stack is this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with [one of my projects](https://github.com/MartinDevillers/omicron/blob/master/src/algorithms/workerizer.ts) where I used the same setup (React + TypeScript + Comlink). Module loading works a little differently with Web Workers, so you can't use imports and exports as you would normally.

Luckily, there's an additional library from Google called [comlink-loader](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink-loader) that solves this issue. You will have to rename the script you want to *workerize* from `customWebWorkers` to `customWebWorkers.worker.js`. Comlink Loader will then automatically pick it up during transpilation and create a wrapped class, which you can then import using `import ParseWorker from 'comlink-loader!../../../customWebWorkers'`. You can then use this wrapped class to execute your method, as you would normally.

```
import ParseWorker from 'comlink-loader!../../../customWebWorkers'

const workerFactory = new ParseWorker()

const worker = await new workerFactory.ParseWorker()

const result = await parseWorker.parseFunc(csvData)
```

**Note 1**: in this example there's two types of `ParseWorker` classes. The one at the top is a factory that can be used to create any number of instances. Basically, each instance is its own Web Worker that runs independently from the rest, which is useful if you want to parallelize your work load across all CPU cores. If this is overkill for your use case, you can also use Comlink Loader in [singleton mode](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink-loader#singleton-mode). This gives you one Web Worker per module.

**Note 2**: both the constructor and any methods on your class need to be awaited, as they've been wrapped in async methods.

**Note 3**: if the contents of your `csvData` variable is large, you may want to use `Comlink.transfer` to prevent the overhead of duplicating the data.

Finally, but this is more a personal observation, my experience with Web Workers in browsers was only so-so. I was hoping to offload CPU-heavy code to improve performance and reduce lag in the UI, which it did.. but it also made the UI "jittery" at times and sometimes "stalled" the whole window. Maybe they work better in a server-side NodeJS context.. not sure..

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! I reworked it all to use the comlink loader as you said, but now I'm seeing a different issue altogether; it seems like the loader fails any time I try to start it up with this error: `        ERROR in ./src/utils/parse.worker.ts (./node_modules/comlink-loader/dist/comlink-worker-loader.js!./src/utils/parse.worker.ts) 33:9
        Module parse failed: Unexpected token (33:9)
        File was processed with these loaders:
         * ./node_modules/comlink-loader/dist/comlink-worker-loader.js` Any idea what's up with this? Have you encountered a similar issue?